# Brew install yarn failed with message `NoMethodError: undefined method path`

Tags: macos, homebrew, yarnpkg

I tried to install `yarn` with `brew install yarn` and got an error message:

```
Error: An exception occurred within a child process: NoMethodError: undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 2):

I updated XCode (through app store) and brew (with command line `brew update`).

I ran `brew doctor` which told me to update xcode toolchain: `softwareupdate --all --install --force`.

I then installed yarn again with `brew install yarn`.

Comment: Sounds like a desirable path of solving the issue.